# Where to put keystore password

Tags: java, encryption

I am sure this topic has been discussed but i couldn't find a proper answer.

I have a keystore into which I am putting encryption keys. I need to encrypt data because although it's on a server behind a firewall, it's pretty important info. I am securing the keystore with a password. I realise that there will always be one weak point in the system, but I was wondering what the best-practice approach for storing keystore passwords was.

A couple of considerations:

1. I am in a web (tomcat) environment.
2. I can't leave it up to the user
   to enter, because the system needs to encrypt/decrypt data without
   the user's intervention

Comment: Best practice is to use a Hardware Security Module (HSM) to store the keys and do the encrypting on the module. Failing that require the password to be entered on startup of you program rather than storing it.

Answer (score 0):

Require the password to the key store to be enter by a human from standard in on startup of your program. That way you don't need to store it anywhere other than in a human brain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also I need to access the key password in my application to encrypt the data. There might be chances that user might forgot the password and in that case we can not decrypt the data

Comment: Then put it into your web.xml file as a context parameter.